# What is the Significance of return in this if condition & while statement?

Tags: c, algorithm

```
/* Given a reference (pointer to pointer) to the head 
of a list and an int, appends a new node at the end */
void append(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data) 
{ 
    /* 1. allocate node */
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 

    struct Node *last = *head_ref; /* used in step 5*/

    /* 2. put in the data */
    new_node->data = new_data; 

    /* 3. This new node is going to be the last node, so make next 
        of it as NULL*/
    new_node->next = NULL; 

    /* 4. If the Linked List is empty, then make the new node as head */
    if (*head_ref == NULL) 
    { 
    *head_ref = new_node; 
    return;
    } 

    /* 5. Else traverse till the last node */
    while (last->next != NULL) 
        last = last->next; 

    /* 6. Change the next of last node */
    last->next = new_node;
    return;
}
```

**What is the use of the return keyword in the above if & while condition?**

Is it necessary to give this return keyword or without this also my program will work fine?

Comment: And there is no 'return' *inside* the `while` loop - that has only one statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` keyword is optional for functions with return type void (since they don't return anything). However, if the return statement is used, it immediately stops the program flow of the function and returns from the function. In your example, using the return within the if statement ensures that the function will not further execute if the condition is true.

However, note that return statement is required if the return type of the function is not void.